# How can I trap the error before the crash with this code

Tags: ios, nsstring

I am receiving data through the audio jack.  It works most of the time however you can receive bad data through it.  I want to be able to trap the error before it crashes.  Here is the code

```
 - (void) updateBytCtl:(NSString*) text {
    //  NSLog(text);
    NSString *subString = [[text componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *expDateString = [[text componentsSeparatedByString:@"="]objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *expDate = [expDateString substringToIndex:4];
    NSString *expDateYear = [expDateString substringToIndex:2];
    NSString *expDateMonth = [expDate substringFromIndex:2];

    subString = [[subString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] objectAtIndex:1];

   }
```

There are a wide variety of reasons that the data could be bad from the reader.  I would like it to just through a general error and get the user to re-swipe the card.

Comment: And don't needlessly split `text` twice. Save the result to an array variable.

Comment: Consider using `NSDateFormatter` or `NSDataDetector` instead of parsing by hand. What will you do when the date and month are backwards from what you expect?

Comment: Zach they come across in the same slots due to the way they are encrypted and the reader brings it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anywhere that you make assumptions about the existence of objects in an arrays or the length of the string, for example:

```
[[text componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:1]
```

You would want to do something like

```
NSArray *components = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
if (components.count > 1) {
    subString = [components objectAtIndex:1];
} else {
    // Display error to user and return
}
```

You don't want to assume an array has a certain index or that a string is a certain length, always perform a check and if your code would fail, display whichever error you want and return.

Comment: Thank you, not sure why I didn't think of that guess I have been over analyzing the problem.  Thank you

Comment: In general **don't ignore errors**. Test for **all** possible errors and **handle** them, an `NSLog()` of an error is not sufficient. Let the user know about the error and provide recovery information for the user.

Comment: Zaph under normal circumstances you are correct, however when receiving data reads from the audio jack you can get a lot of bad data and there is really no rhyme or reason for it.